# How to get the second value in the echo in PHP?

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements, echo

I have some options to select and would like to set some textinputs to visible or hidden depending on what user selects. I have the functionality already but in this case I need to take the second value of the echo and check if its equal to something, I can currently only check the first value of the echo:

```
<select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="if (this.value==''){this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='hidden'}else{this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='visible'};">
   <option value='Select'>Select</option>
   <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>;
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

So, I need to get ONLY the value of  `$row['serial_or_imei']` and compare `onchange="if (this.value=='')` , how can I do that?

**EDIT: further explanation**

I need to read the value of `$row['serial_or_imei']` which could be empty, 'serial' OR 'imei', so, one of these three. 
P.S: I must keep the `$row['id']` in the `value` attribute because I am passing that value later to server so dont suggest removing that.

Comment: In case your `id` and `serial_or_imei` both are numeric then ideally you should prepare it using any delimiter.

Comment: You may also assign the value of `$row['serial_or_imei']` to a different attribute and then compare it.

Comment: @SwatantraKumar they are not both numeric, serial_or_imei is indeed string or it can be null

Comment: What I mean, is how you are going to differentiate out of a string, which part is id and which one is serial_or_imei. Maybe think about a delimiter like underscore `value="<?php echo $row['id'] . '_'. $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"`

Comment: Is this question correctly tagged? If values come from PHP there's no need to send them back to server; they're already there, all you need to pass is the selected ID. But I can spot some inline JavaScript; a clean way to pass additional data to JavaScript is using `data-` HTML attributes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this select component is dynamic, so I am fetching these values from the server AND passing them to the server again what I selected after submitting. I need ´$row['id']´ to send it to server, and I need `$row['serial_or_imei']` to make some fields visible or hide them.

Comment: If you mean dynamic as in "on every page load the ID-IMEI relationships change", I'd just add a dedicated hidden field called something like `id_serial_or_imei_map`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that's what I also though but what field and how can I add that?

Comment: A clear example of the end result might help us help you. By reading this, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @LouisCharette just updated with a little more clarification, please let me know if its still not clear to you.

Comment: But define "read" the value. On the server, or in the "onchange"? What is the purpose of the "onchange" ? Having the whole form might help understand the "onchange" purpose.

Comment: @LouisCharette yes, I want to read it in the "onchange". So depending on the value of it when "onchange" is triggered then I am setting some fields to hidden or visible as you can see in the code.

Comment: I asked you if this was really a PHP question. The `onchange` attribute contains client-side JavaScript code. JavaScript and PHP are different languages.

Answer (score 2):

You add a new custom attribute `serial` and supply the value of `serial_or_imei` to it and then compare in javascript with `onchange="if (this.value=='')`

```
<select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="if (this.value==''){this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='hidden'}else{this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='visible'};">
    <option value='Select'>Select</option>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>" data-serial="<?php echo $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>;
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

EDIT: Attribute “serial” is not allowed on element “option”. Changed this to data-seial.

Comment: you cant add custom attributes

Comment: Your custom attribute should be `data-serial` instead of `serial` to be valid HTML.

Comment: nope, if I add custom attributes it prints the values of that attribute instead of Value, and I dont want that.

Comment: @rtzr  Didn't get you by can't add custom attributes.

Comment: Ah, got it.check.

Comment: @LouisCharette Good catch. Attribute “serial” is not allowed on element “option”. Modified it.

Comment: @SwatantraKumar doesn't make any better difference, it prints the values of `data-serial` instead of `value`

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the value of an array in the `onchange` by assign the value to a variable which will be a quite neat format as

```
<?php $value = echo $row['serial_or_imei']; ?>
<select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="if (this.value=='<?php empty($value)?>'){this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='hidden'}else{this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='visible'};">
   <option value='Select'>Select</option>
   <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>;
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: no, sorry for the misunderstanding, I dont want to compare, I want to check the value of `$row['serial_or_imei']`

Comment: can you please explain it again ?

Comment: I want to check if `$row['serial_or_imei']`is empty or contains a string in `onchange="if (this.value=='')`

Comment: Ok for that you can use empty function as check out my edited answer.

Comment: the way you are setting the value of `$row['serial_or_imei']` to `$value` its totally wrong, you know that right? You aren't actually even assigning the value there.

Comment: The value has been already assigned the line before the if condition please do check that.

Comment: you must assign it only when user has selected whatever he has selected. So inside the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `one attribute` to `option element` and test with it. something like

```
<select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="if (this.getAttribute('data')==''){this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='hidden'}else{this.form['device_imei_textinput'].style.visibility='visible'};">
   <option value='Select'>Select</option>
   <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
     <option data="<?php echo $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>;
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried but then it prints that value instead the values of the attribute `value`

Answer (score 0):

You say you need the values back to server because they change dynamically. A clean way would be to have a dedicated hidden field:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="map[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['serial_or_imei']; ?>">
<? } ?>
```

Here's a full self-contained script to illustrate it:

```
<?php

$random_serial_or_imei = range(1000, 9999);
shuffle($random_serial_or_imei);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $result[] = [
        'id' => $i,
        'serial_or_imei' => $random_serial_or_imei[$i],
        'name' => "Name #$i",
    ];
}

?>
<select name="device_type_id">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="map[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['serial_or_imei']; ?>">
<? } ?>
```

This prints something like:

```
<select name="device_type_id">
    <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="0">Name #0</option>
            <option value="1">Name #1</option>
            <option value="2">Name #2</option>
            <option value="3">Name #3</option>
            <option value="4">Name #4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="map[0]" value="9513">
    <input type="hidden" name="map[1]" value="3931">
    <input type="hidden" name="map[2]" value="3971">
    <input type="hidden" name="map[3]" value="4476">
    <input type="hidden" name="map[4]" value="6429">
```

Selected type can be found at `$_POST['device_type_id']` and the corresponding IMEI at `$_POST['map'][ $_POST['device_type_id'] ]`.

Comment: however, I need to check what has the user selected in order to change visibility of those two components and your code does something else. Basically, I need `$row['id']` to send it to server when submitting, and `$row['serial_or_imei']` to set visibility of some textinputs to visible or hidden depending on the value of `$row['serial_or_imei']`. So two different thngs.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to read the IMEI. To show and hide HTML elements you can use CSS (`display: none`); that's a different subject.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information from the comments, I think this solution is what you are looking for. Note I move the `onchange` to a function for clarity.

You can see the "three" option hides the text input as it doesn't have a `imei`.

Also notice how I use the `data-` attribute inside your option so you can retrieve that information as well, independent of the option `id`. Also note the `this.form['device_imei_textinput']` didn't worked. The `elements` reference is required.

```js
function check_imei(obj, form) {
    var imei = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-imei');

    if (imei == '') {
        form.elements.device_imei_textinput.style.visibility='hidden';
    } else {
        form.elements.device_imei_textinput.style.visibility='visible';
    }  
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="check_imei(this, this.form);">
        <option value='Select'>Select</option>
        <option value="1" data-imei="foo">One</option>
        <option value="2" data-imei="bar">Two</option>
        <option value="3" data-imei="">Three</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="device_imei_textinput" name="device_imei_textinput" />
</form>
```

Mirror of example : https://jsfiddle.net/asp1hewx/

**EDIT** : To address the PHP side of things, the form above could be generated with :

```
<form>
    <select id="type_id" name="device_type_id" onchange="check_imei(this, this.form);">
        <option value='Select'>Select</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>" data-imei="<?php $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="device_imei_textinput" name="device_imei_textinput" />
</form>
```

Comment: nope, you have left out the $row['id'] which I said I am using it somewhere else, so dont remove that.

Comment: It you can still place it in the `value`. I removed all PHP from this example, to make the snippet functional. In this case, the option would be `<option value="<?php echo $row['id'] . $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>" data-imei="<?php $row['serial_or_imei'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>`

Comment: See edit for better formatting. If this doesn't solve your issue regarding the row id, please explain a bit more what you want to achieve regarding the `id`.